Vitest doesn't pick up tsconfig.json include property for .vue files
When using vitest to run my typescript unittests I run into an issue when testing vue component tests that involve file inclusion.
I'm using 2 folders for my typescript files: 'ts' for all pure typescript classes and 'src' for all files that depend on frameworks like vue. I'm also using relative import statements and made sure the  include paths are properly handled by the tsconfig. I'm not using vite for my production code but webpack.
vitests.config.ts 
tsconfig.base.json 
ts/tsconfig.json 
src/tsconfig.json 
src/tests/pages/WelcomeTests.ts 
src/pages/WelcomePage.vue 
src/datastores/store.ts 
I noticed that vitest doesn't resolve the absolute paths of the import statements. And gives errors like:

FAIL  src/tests/pages/WelcomeTests.ts [ src/tests/pages/WelcomeTests.ts ]
Error: Failed to resolve import "datastores/store" from "src/pages/WelcomePage.vue". Does the file exist?
Plugin: vite:import-analysis

I tried using vite-tsconfig-paths but then it started to become awkward. I've installed both vitest-tsconfig-paths and vite-tsconfig-paths.
vitest-tsconfig-paths could not be imported because of this error:

Could not find a declaration file for module 'vitest-tsconfig-paths'. '/home/user/dev/project/node_modules/vitest-tsconfig-paths/dist/index.mjs' implicitly has an 'any' type.
There are types at '/home/user/dev/project/node_modules/vitest-tsconfig-paths/dist/index.d.ts', but this result could not be resolved when respecting package.json "exports". The 'vitest-tsconfig-paths' library may need to update its package.json or typings.ts(7016)

And for the vite-tsconfig-paths module I found that the option 'extensions' is not available which I need to include the .json extension which is default not used:

Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'extensions' does not exist in type 'PluginOptions'.ts(2353)

First question I have is which npm package I actually need: vitest-tsconfig-paths or vite-tsconfig-paths. And secondly how to use the tsconfig with .json extension which I thought is pretty standard. Also notice how the absolute path from the WelcomeTests to the WelcomePage seems to work but not from the WelcomePage.vue to the store.
Relevant code bits:
WelcomeTests.ts
import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import WelcomePage from "pages/WelcomePage.vue";

WelcomPage.vue
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import { useActivityStore, usePageStore } from "datastores/store";

vitest.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from "vitest/config";
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";
import inject from "@rollup/plugin-inject";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        inject({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
        }),
        tsconfigPaths({
            projects: ["./ts/", "./src/"]
        }),
        vue(),
    ],
    optimizeDeps: {
        include: ["node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"],
    },
    test: {
        globals: true,
        include: ["ts/tests/**/*Tests.ts", "src/tests/**/*Tests.ts"],
        environment: "happy-dom",
        setupFiles: "ts/tests/test.setup.ts",
        silent: true,
    },
    /*resolve: {
        alias: {
            datastores: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/datastores/"),
            components: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/components/"),
        },
    },*/
});

Alternative I tried is to alias every folder in vitest.config.ts but I ran into another problem which is that I have duplicate foldernames under both the ts and src folder. For instance they both have a datastore and a components folder.

vitest-tsconfig-paths doesn't seem to do anything useful in comparison to vite-... . ".json extension which I thought is pretty standard" - can you clarify? If you want to import json files without an extension, it's not really standard

I meant the tsconfig files which always have a .json file extension. The npm package usage page shows these file extensions as default: extensions: string[]
File extensions to search for.
Defaults to .ts | .tsx | .js | .jsx | .mjs;
I might have  interpreted this wrongly as probably not the tsconfig file extension was meant here. Anyway I left out the extensions option.

Only option that works for me is to split vitest config into a vitest config for each folder and use the resolve alias property. Additionally I had to rename the ts/datstore folder to ts/data as well.
vitest-src.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from "vitest/config";
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";
import inject from "@rollup/plugin-inject";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import path from "path";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        inject({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
        }),
        tsconfigPaths({
            projects: ["./src"],
        }),
        vue(),
    ],
    optimizeDeps: {
        include: ["node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"],
    },
    test: {
        globals: true,
        include: ["src/tests/**/*Tests.ts"],
        environment: "happy-dom",
        setupFiles: "ts/tests/test.setup.ts",
        silent: true,
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            datastores: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/datastores/"),
            components: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/components/"),
            data: path.resolve(__dirname, "./ts/data/"),
            models: path.resolve(__dirname, "./ts/models/"),
            tools: path.resolve(__dirname, "./ts/tools/"),
            views: path.resolve(__dirname, "./ts/views/"),
        },
    },
});

vitest-ts.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from "vitest/config";
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";
import inject from "@rollup/plugin-inject";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        inject({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
        }),
        tsconfigPaths({
            projects: ["./ts"],
        }),
    ],
    optimizeDeps: {
        include: ["node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"],
    },
    test: {
        globals: true,
        include: ["ts/tests/**/*Tests.ts"],
        environment: "happy-dom",
        setupFiles: "./ts/tests/test.setup.ts",
        silent: true,
    },
});

In package.json I then had to explicitly provide the config filename and change my scripts.
package.json
{
    "name": "project",
    "description": "MyProject",
    "version": "4.1.3",
    "author": "me",
    "license": "closed",
    "private": true,
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "all": "npm run test && npm run build-prod",
        "dev": "npm run build-dev",
        "build": "npm run build-prod",
        "build-dev": "webpack --mode=development --progress",
        "build-prod": "webpack --mode=production --progress && rm dist/main.js.map & npm run minify",
        "lint": "npm run tslint & npm run plint",
        "tslint": "eslint ts/ src/",
        "tslint-fix": "eslint --fix ts/ src/",
        "plint": "phplint '**/*.php' '!vendor/**' '!node_modules/**' 1> /dev/null",
        "test": "npm run phptest & npm run tstest",
        "pretest": "npm run lint",
        "tstest": "vitest run -c vitest-ts.config.ts && vitest run -c vitest-src.config.ts",
        "srctest-watch": "vitest -c vitest-src.config.ts",
        "tstest-watch": "vitest -c vitest-ts.config.ts",

